# Unique Integer ID for a non primary key field for Entities in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unique

I have an Entity type say URLInfo which keeps info about URLs. The primary key of this entity is URL itself ( that makes sure that I always have unique URLs in the datastore). I also want unique integer id for each url so that sharing the id becomes easier. Though, I can use GUIDs, but that is not a preferred thing for me. How can I achieve this requirement? Integer Ids need not be sequential ( preferred, if they are). Entities can be generated at a faster rate (that means I can't keep a common counter to update each time I generate a new URL record). This is what I have tried so far - In the URLInfo class, I defined a field - Long Id and annotate it with @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY) in the hope that it will get automatically generated with the unique value. But when I save the new entity (with id set as null), it saves the entity in the datastore but doesn't assign any value to this field.

I am trying all this on a local machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Probably I forgot to mention that I am using JDO. The annotation you suggested is not available (GeneratedValue cannot be resolved to a type).

Comment: Ok. I assume that your using JPA.

Only you mention the use of annotation `@Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)`, be sure to also use the `@PrimaryKey` annotation together.

You also have to be careful with the key type. Check out the link: 

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Keys

Comment: Hi Angel. I want it without @PrimaryKey annotation. My primary key is URL. If I make the integer id as primary key, I run into the risk of my URLs getting duplicated in the datastore (if you know any strategy using which I can avoid this risk, I would be more than happy and adopt that strategy). In a nutshell, I need to store unique URLs along with their unique integer ids.